# Fetch Contacts From yahoo using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, yahoo

how can i fetch the yahoo contacts in asp.net any source code or any reference.

Comment: Can you tell us anything more specific about what you're up to? I might be able to provide more specific help if I know more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo's full .net specific documentation for this stuff can be found at http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/

Answer (score 0):

The [Yahoo Contacts API](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) - this is a webservice, so you can simply access it as such.

OR

Read http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/ and Use WebClient in ASP.NET.
You can take idea how to use API from [here](http://gnillydev.blogspot.com/2007/10/yahoo-contact-import-class-in-c.html).

Comment: That link on how to use the API points to a 3 year old article which doesn't work anymore.